# How to control log levels in C#

Tags: c#

For a C# library we're building, we've implemented a logging facility using `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`. The library is using a nullable `ILogger`, which is injected by the user of the library, like this:

```
var client = new Client(app.Logger)
```

The `app` is an AspNetCore application, which has a configured logger, and is injected into the Client. However, I'd like to control the log levels using the standard logging configuration as in `appsettings.json`:

```
"Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Debug",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Information",
    "System.Net.Http.HttpClient": "Information"
  }
}
```

I'd like to add an entry here, to control the logging, like this:

```
"Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Debug",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Information",
    "System.Net.Http.HttpClient": "Information",
    "MyLibrary": "Trace"   // <--- like this
  }
}
```

The challenge is that the namespace of the logger is not `MyLibrary`, but the name of the current logger printed is `rp-dotnet-sample[0]`, instead of something like `MyLibrary`.

My question now is: how do I get to a situation in which I can develop this library and control the log levels external to the library?

Comment: Do you inject `ILogger` or `ILogger<Client>`?

Comment: I'm injecting ILogger. I initially tried by injecting an ILogger<Client>, but I didn't know how to get access to one or to create one.

Comment: Well, `ILogger<T>` is a named logger and gets its name from the class name including the namespace. The `ILogger<T>` instance is automatically built by DI container

Comment: Thanks for that, appreciate it. But when you say: "The ILogger<T> instance is automatically built by DI container", what does that mean? How do I get access to it, and inject it in my library? Btw, the library is in a different project than my webapp project.

Comment: let the DI container create the instances of your classes. You can write extension methods to register all of your types to the DI so for the consumer it is just a call of `builder.Services.AddMyFancyLibrary();` and everything is wired up

Comment: Have a look how Swashbuckle implemented it [SwaggerGenServiceCollectionExtensions](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen/DependencyInjection/SwaggerGenServiceCollectionExtensions.cs)

Comment: Thanks, appreciate your help, but I'm feeling a bit silly for not understanding much of this. I'm not sure who and my library is being used, so if someone isn't using DI, how can they inject the correct logger then?

Comment: You use DI (Dependency Injection) and anybody has to, because you have to inject the dependencies. And it is very easy to handle if you use a DI container. Without a DI container you have to do it manually (of course). But you were talking about asp.net core applications where a DI container is one of the basic needs.

Comment: You should not care about the ones who do not want a DI container and go the very hard way. Just my 5ct